# Javascript undefined array in function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've written a function that takes `plevel` (integer) and `slevel` (array of strings of numbers) and finds the smallest difference between `plevel` and a value in `slevel`. However, when I run the script, it is unresponsive and the debugger says that `diff` is undefined.

```
var findDiff = function findDiff(plevel, slevel) {
  var diff = new Array();

  for (i=0; i<=slevel.length; i++) {
    sleveli = parseInt(slevel[i]);
    diff.push(Math.abs(plevel-sleveli));
  }

  if (diff.length > 1){
    diff.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    return diff[0]
  }
  else{
    return diff[0];  
  }
}
```

The function is invoked here:

```
var matches = new Array();
var newFetch = Data.find().fetch();
for(i = 0; i <= newFetch.length; i++ ){
    pointsMatch = 0
    var difference = findDiff(newFetch[i].level, spec.level);
    pointsMatch -= (difference*3);
    matches.push([newFetch[i], pointsMatch])
}
console.log(matches)
```

`Data` is a mongoDB collection. `spec.level` is an array of strings of numbers stored as a property in an object.

Comment: Can you also show an example of how you invoke this function?

Comment: Isn't this index out of range by the way?
`i<=slevel.length`

Comment: Ok so first of all, `i<..` and not `i<=..`. Second, `findDiff = function(plevel, slevel)` is enough, no need to name twice. Third, `parseInt(string)` returns NaN so these are the values you're gonna get. And 4th, I ran it and it doesn't say diff is undefined.

Comment: @OmriAharon `parseInt(string)` doesn't return `NaN` if the string is a valid numeric string.

Comment: @PaulRoub Yes, I should have written it more clearly. `parseInt(string which is not a number)`, as I don't really know how he's calling it.

Comment: We still don't know what's in `newFetch` or `spec.level`, and so can't reproduce the error.

Comment: @Omri Aharon Assigning an anonymous function to a named variable will result in some debuggers generating an error within an anonymous function, making it harder to find. Naming the function twice is, in fact, the best practice if it has to be assigned to a variable.

Comment: @A.Duff Then what's the benefit over defining `function findDiff(a,b)` if you only need to call the function later ?

Comment: @Omri Aharon If all you're doing is calling it like he's doing here, then there's no benefit. But it's a matter of coding style. OP apparently feels that it's best practice to name all functions as well as assigning them to variables so you don't need to keep track of when to do it and when not to. Not everyone agrees, but it's probably something there will never be universal consensus on, just like whether or not to comment rather than documenting everything in unit tests.

Comment: also remember variable hoisting... `var foo = function foo()` is a named function expression whereas just `function foo` is a function statement. The latter is hoisted, the former isn't. A Duff is right that named function expressions, versus anonymous function expressions, are useful for debugging.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Comment: @A.Duff With all due respect to OP, OP appears to clearly be a novice and I would not assume that they are consciously following any particular set of best practices.

Comment: @JLRishe Well he's a novice with two upvotes. I've actually only seen the double naming syntax among people who know what they're doing, and are familiar with debugging Javascript code. Either he knows what he's doing or he got it from someone who does. I don't think he just decided to use a best practice randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point out name space pollution, which may cause serious troubles. In my understanding, you have two cases of namespace pollution, one of it creates an endless loop.

You have actually an inner an outer loop, separated by a function. Your outer for loop:

```
for(i = 0; i <= newFetch.length; i++ ){
    pointsMatch = 0
    ...
```

And then your inner for loop:

```
for (i=0; i<=slevel.length; i++) {
  sleveli = parseInt(slevel[i]);
  ...
```

Because of the missing `var` before `i`, both for loop definitions are actually like this:

```
for (window.i=0; ...
```

So the inner loop overwrites the variable `i` the outer loop depends on to terminate. `i` is "polluting" namespace.

The second case is harmless:

```
sleveli = parseInt(slevel[i]);
```

Because of the missing `var`, this results in fact in

```
window.sleveli = parseInt(slevel[i]);
```

Better would be

```
var sleveli = parseInt(slevel[i]);
```

But this is a time bomb.

I suggest you add `var` to the definitions of `i` in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the people in the comments are right; we need to see some more of your input to debug this properly. But you can simplify your code a lot by tracking the mins as you go:

```
var findDiff = function findDiff(plevel, slevel) {
  var min = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  for (i=0; i<slevel.length; i++) {
    sleveli = parseInt(slevel[i]);
    var diff = Math.abs(plevel-sleveli);
    min = Math.min(min, diff)
  }
  return min;
}

var a = ["1", "2", "10", "17"]
var p = 6

// We're expecting 4 as the min diff
console.log(findDiff(p, a))
// ...prints out 4 :-)
```

http://repl.it/ceX

As Omri points out, use `<` not `<=` in your for loop.

Note - Number is not always available -- see here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

You could alternatively set the initial min to something suitably large for your likely data, like 2^10